# glassfish: redirect all url to index

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, glassfish, glassfish-3

I'm working on the java ee application using glassfish 3 server and jsf.
I want all of requests to urls starting from my context root to be redirected to my index.xhtml.
For example, if a user types:
my-host/my-app-context-root/lgsfdjglksjdflgjldskfjg-anything
I want this request to be redirected to:
my-host/my-app-context-root/index.xhtml

So I want to know how can I implement this rule. If it's possible, I would like to do it somehow using Java/jsf or web.xml or some other files which belongs to my application only. I want to avoid to do any "general" server configurations, such as setting properties "redirect_n" as it is suggested [there](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2416/gixrb.html).

Thanks in advance and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a servlet filter with mapping "/*". Then use `HttpServletRequest#getRequestURI()` to check whether this is a request for js/css files or any other request and you can accordingly redirect to index.xhtml.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use a servlet with / in web.xml. This servlet would Act as the Default servlet for your application and could output the content of index.xhtml.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying now to do something like this, but I use Servlet Filter instead of Servlet. It catches all requests and forwards them to index, but I faced with a problem - it also forwards all requests for js and css resources(